# Retrieving a WIF bits private key

Tags: private-key, electrum, public-key, wallet-import-format, programming-bitcoin-book

Suppose I have a Wif private key from Electrum 4.0.9:

L2pt3eVopnxfBBvMwrJV2saZeAyQfF77UQSH5WGj5q9LBS6WWBmN ( this one or the other generated from the seed is non used of course )

with a corresponding public key:

14k8mYFC1LBWiBN8WSxpJN48jQYX1FZ6kz

I am using the code from the book "programming bitcoin" and the way we create private key is by converting the bits of a secret phrase like this:

```
secret = little_endian_to_int(hash256(b'dat_test_private_key'))
```

So I was thinking I just had to put the private key derived from L2pt3eVopnxfBBvMwrJV2saZeAyQfF77UQSH5WGj5q9LBS6WWBmN instead of "dat_test_private_key"

then we do more step to get our private key here:

> https://github.com/jimmysong/programmingbitcoin/blob/master/code-ch13/ecc.py

Then to get our public key:

> public_key = print(private_key.point.address(testnet=False))

But no mater what I tried I dont have the same public key as electrum, so I guess I must be off something or they use a different WIF format or the way they derive public key

Comment: What do you mean by "original bits"?

Comment: I have updated my post, but I guess I am gonna go for the bitcoin libraries and dont go too deep for my project, I have even had a reply from Jimmy song for my problem, but it hadnt fixed it

Comment: There are tons of ways for converting passwords/phrases/seeds into keys. Presumably Electrum is using a very different one. That doesn't mean any is right or wrong.

Answer (score 0):

> So I was thinking I just had to put the private key derived from L2pt3eVopnxfBBvMwrJV2saZeAyQfF77UQSH5WGj5q9LBS6WWBmN instead of "dat_test_private_key"
> Blockquote

Are you trying to hash the private key and use it as the
secret?
You could try something like this instead:

```
secret = int(derived_private_key_hex, 16)
```